# Swiperjs: Can't Import coverflow styles vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I am trying to make a VueJS slider using [swiperjs](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper) with coverflow effect like this one: [Coverflow Example](https://swiperjs.com/demos/240-effect-coverflow/core.html)

But the effect isn't applied to the slider. I guess I am not importing the css for that as in there is a special file for it under

> node_modules>swiper/components/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.less

Here is a [full CSS styles](https://swiperjs.com/vue#css-styles) available.
How can I import the css in my Nuxt component?

Comment: Please provide some code example because right now, it's hard to help you. Did you tried `import 'swiper/components/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.less';` after `<script>` and before `export default {` as shown in the documentation?

Comment: yeah That's what I did but when I looked at the file on swiperjs githu repo it was empty so That's not the problem anymore.

Comment: This style file can be found here: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/3aad554cb4/src/components/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.less

Comment: yeah but as you see it's empty, so it's not what causing the problem.

Comment: In the documentation, it's say that it's required. It being void is not an issue by itself. The package may not need more CSS for the overflow effect (maybe everything is already in the base style).

Comment: how can I importing when it's in node_modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure of the actual code that you've written so far but did you checked the official demo example in Vue? https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-coverflow
This will not change in Nuxt and you can keep it scoped in the component.

```html
<template>
  <swiper :effect="'coverflow'" 
    :grabCursor="true"
    :centeredSlides="true"
    slidesPerView="auto"
    :coverflowEffect="{
      'rotate': 50,
      'stretch': 0,
      'depth': 100,
      'modifier': 1,
      'slideShadows': true
    }" 
    :pagination="true"
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide><img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" /></swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

<script>
// Import Swiper Vue.js components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';

import "swiper/components/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.min.css"
import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css"

import './style.css'; // this one is not required so far

// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, {
  EffectCoverflow,Pagination
} from 'swiper/core';

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([EffectCoverflow,Pagination]);

export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this actually helped, I had to import EffectCoverflow from swiper then pass it to swiper.use()  ```Swiper.use([Pagination, EffectCoverflow])```